# Extracting centers from cmeans

Tags: r

from this cmeans function :

```
 x1=c(55,60,75,80)
 x2=c(30,20,15,23)
 x3=c(4,3,2,6)
 x=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
  library(e1071)
  fcm=cmeans(x,2,80)
  fcm

  #  Fuzzy c-means clustering with 2 clusters

  #  Cluster centers:
  #      v1       v2       v3
  #  1 57.40432 25.29914 3.532451
  #  2 77.40394 19.06642 4.018641

   # Memberships:
   #   1          2
   # [1,] 0.95674506 0.04325494
   # [2,] 0.89673114 0.10326886
   # [3,] 0.05938016 0.94061984
   # [4,] 0.04769093 0.95230907

   # Closest hard clustering:
   #  [1] 1 1 2 2
```

from that result how to extract just  `Cluster centers` part :
how to do it in r ??? without the name of variable

```
 1 57.40432 25.29914 3.532451
 2 77.40394 19.06642 4.018641
```

Comment: You found that function in some package not in (base) R. Maybe consult its documentation, presumably located at `?cmeans`

Comment: When asking for help with non-base functions, you should explicitly list the pacakge(s) involved. Also, include sample data to make the question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: yes from `e1071` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matrix is given by `fcm$centers`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but how delete the variable names .

Comment: @user5934339, `unname(fcm$centers)`.